# Android - How can I put database rows into a ListView?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I am trying to view the content of my database by listing it in a `ListView`. What am i doing wrong? The goal is to load a list of the database data when the page loads after a button click on the homepage.

The XML page simply has a `ListView`, named "studentList", inside a `ScrollView`

Java code:

```
public class edit_student extends AppCompatActivity {
    private dbasemanager dBase;
    private ListView studentInfoList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.edit_student);

        dBase.openReadable();
        studentInfoList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.studentList);
        ArrayList<String> dBaseContent = dBase.retrieveRows();
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdpt = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dBaseContent);
        studentInfoList.setAdapter(arrayAdpt);
        dBase.close();
    }
}
```

This is `openReadable()` Function:

```
public dbasemanager openReadable() throws android.database.SQLException {
    helper = new SQLHelper(context);
    db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
    return this;
}
```

This is the `retrieveRows()` Function:

```
 public ArrayList<String> retrieveRows() {
    ArrayList<String> studentRows = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] columns = new String[] {"sid", "first_name", "last_name"};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(Table_Name, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
        studentRows.add(cursor.getString(0) + ", " + cursor.getString(1) 
                        + ", " + cursor.getString(2));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
        cursor.close();
    }
    return studentRows;
}
```

Logcat:

[image: logcat]

Comment: You need to create a custom `ArrayAdapter`

Comment: @CodeWalker to show a single ArrayList of strings you don't need a custom adapter.

Comment: What is you exact problem? the list it not showing anything? are you getting any error? BTW: are you sure that qhe array retuned by retrieveRows() is not empty?

Comment: @adalPaRi The app crashes when I try to load the page with the list view. I seem to be getting NullPointerExcption.  The retrieveRows() does return an output. I tested using toast.maketext and it does contain my test data.

Comment: Can you post your logcat then?

Comment: @adalPaRi here is a screenshot: http://imgur.com/XrfPWOV

Comment: @nanjeroechizen you are providing few information. Let's chat to help you: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123416/nanjero-echizen

Comment: BTW, your nullpointer is in line 17 of edit_student.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a null pointer in line 17.

You need to construct databasemanager object before call it

```
public class edit_student extends AppCompatActivity {
    private dbasemanager dBase;
    private ListView studentInfoList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.edit_student);

        // construct databasemanager
        dBase = new dbasemanager(...);

        dBase.openReadable();
        studentInfoList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.studentList);
        ArrayList<String> dBaseContent = dBase.retrieveRows();
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdpt = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dBaseContent);
        studentInfoList.setAdapter(arrayAdpt);
        dBase.close();
    }
}
```

BTW, I recommend you to use java code conventions to name classes.
For example: edit_student should be editStudent and dbasemanager should be DBManager or DbManager.